# Computer heats more using Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: nvidia, overheating, temperature

My computer's configuration is:

**Ubuntu 14.10 

NVIDIA GeForce 630M 

Intel i5-3210M 

6Gb RAM 

1Tb HD**

I have always used Windows, and after installing Ubuntu last year I could feel that the heat coming out from my notebook was hotter than usual. After few searches I discovered the `psensor` software, used to check the computer's temperature, and I could see that its heat was over 60 degrees Celcius. 
After few more searches few days ago, I followed users' instructions to change my NVIDIA's drivers from the stantard one in computer configurations and to install other programs using the Terminal to better control the use of computer's power. One of them is called `bumblebee`, but the other one I really don't remember, except for the `gpu` initials. 
I must say that the temperature really has decreased around 20 degrees Celcius, now it's around 43 ~ 45, but when playing a really simple game (Tibia) it increases again to 60, but the heat coming out isn't as hot as it was before.

I really don't know the average temperature when using Windows. I want to know if someone has a better solution for me for these specific configuration, to reduce the heat from my computer, like another install, or perhaps those I've installed isn't the right one...

Thank you so much.

Comment: This might be driver related. Even further, solutions come in the rarest ways. Try upgrading your kernel to 3.17

Comment: CheddieMerai thank you for the tip. It didn't decreased the temperature but made the boot really faster. Perhaps this is the regular temperature for my computer, maybe it was the same on Windows. As I said, I never knew the exactly temperature. Also, when I installed the packages, a error message kept appearing saying it had a problem to install nvidia-340, so I changed for an older version in the list and everything seems normal.

Comment: Reading over your question, you only made mention to an unusual heat. What about the fan? Is it spinning normally or louder?

Comment: It's always normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some utilities for reducing power consumption  and heating, such as `tlp` and `laptop mode tools` (if it's a laptop, of course).

To install tlp do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

As for laptop mode tools, it's in the software center.

I've got tlp myself, and on average my temperature is 75 C ( which is 167 F  ). Of course, it's lower if I use it less intensively, and it's the same temperature I get in Windows 7.

Among other things, make sure your machine is properly ventilated. If it's a laptop, try investing in larger battery that will raise your laptop a bit and thus open air passage ways, or at least in cooling pad ( everything is on amazon these day, guys, and reasonably priced ).

[source](http://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-linux-mint-17/)

Additional tip: it's possible the cooling paste that is placed between the CPU and hit sink it drying out, hence you may need to open the laptop up and add the paste. I've had it happen once that my laptop was overheating close to 90 degrees celsius; after I opened up the laptop,  I realized the paste dried out. After adding it - everything went back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It also didn't make any difference, which makes me think that 45 C is my regular temperature.

Comment: linrunner does not appear to have packages for 14.10

Comment: @Catskul Have you updated after you added the repository  ?

Comment: @serg, yep, it claimed that it doesn't exist. It seems they only support the LTS releases. I did manage to manually download the Trusty/14.04 version and install it, but the package manager did not offer that solution automatically upon `apt-get install`