# Ubuntu 14-10 warmed my laptop

Tags: 14.10

Recently I installed ubuntu 14.10 and I've noted how the temperature grow up (my laptop is hp pavilion dv6-7084la, intel core i7-3610QM, 2.30GHzx8, 8GB RAM). Tipically, when I am working only with firefox, this parameter doesn't descend from 55-60°(C), and, as I start another aplications (like texmaker, amarok, etc.) temperature take values around 75°. Particularly, when I open a txt file with gedit and I write on it, temperature has reached 95°. 
Can someone help me with this?, or it is inevitable the change to another version of ubuntu?
Thank you

Comment: That's odd. Everyone is saying graphics cards, but you said that if gets that hot, from gedit? You need to check processes before, `ps aux` and then check again after you've opened gedit to see if something else running when you open it. Also check out all the logs, before and after. If you don't know what to check search online for ubuntu logs, system logs, device logs, Kernel logs, etc. I hope you can get this solved because I build full Android system ROMs on my laptop and other stuff at the same time, like watching a movie online and it only gets up to about 85 degrees Celsius

Answer (score 2):

Graphics card drivers generally causes these kind of heating issues. Go to Unity>Additional Drivers and check whether you are using the latest stable graphics drivers or not. In your case, it is GT630M which has heating issues even with Windows 7 and 8.

If you have it installed already the latest drivers and still problem persists, try Option 1.

Option 1: [TLP](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tlp-0-6-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/): There is a [similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542065/computer-heats-more-using-ubuntu-1), please go through it first. However, some people are saying that using TLP actually causes their system to overheat further. If that happens to your system, then remove TLP and go to Option 2.

Option 2: [Thermal D + Intel P state](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html): This worked for me, might help you too.

PS: I have ASUS K55VM which has the same graphics card. So, its likely to work out for you too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade microcode for your Intel processor.

`sudo apt-get install iucode-tool`

2. Enable intel pstate by adding it after splash in your grub config:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=enable"`

3. Change the cpu governor settings in TLP (and un-comment these lines):

`sudo nano /etc/default/tlp`

`CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=performance`

`CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=powersave`

4. Need more info about your graphics card.

Comment: For upgrading the microcode of the Intel CPU, this has to be performed every boot. The package `intel-microcode` will do this for you automatically in Ubuntu. No need to install the `iucode-tool` package as far as I know.